# on load and on click hide/show div

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is to have all paragraphs but #p0 hidden on load.
Additionally I want to show a paragraph if user clicks on it's sibling span, and hide all other paragraphs

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <h1>
        <span id="span0">Lorem</span>
        <p id="p0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </h1>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h1>
        <span id="span1">Lorem2</span>
        <p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </h1>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h1>
        <span id="span2">Lorem3</span>
        <p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </h1> 
   </li>
...
```

Comment: I'd assign a class to each paragraph - the same class anme and then use JQuery $('.classnam').hide() on load

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but wouldn't that hide all paragraphs? I need the first one to be visible on load

Comment: oh, I see, you want the first one visible on load and the rest to show up as one clicks on span? Would you want to hide them again if someone clicks on span repeatedly?

Comment: @Nele check my update.

Comment: @ElenaDBA Yes, but also when when one clicks on span to hide all paragraphs that are not a sibling to it. And i dont want the sibling paragraph hidden if someone clicks on span repeatedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('p:not("#p0")').hide();

$('span').on('click',function() {
    $('p').hide();
    $(this).next('p').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
   <li>
      <h1>
        <span id="span0">Lorem</span>
        <p id="p0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </h1>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h1>
        <span id="span1">Lorem2</span>
        <p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </h1>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h1>
        <span id="span2">Lorem3</span>
        <p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </h1> 
   </li>
 </ul>
```

If you wish to isolate this from other `p`'s / `span`'s on the page you could use the ['prefixed-by' attribute selector (`^=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) ...

```js
$('p[id^="p"]:not("#p0")').hide();

$('span[id^="span"]').on('click',function() {
    $('p[id^="p"]').hide();
    $(this).next('p[id^="p"]').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
   <li>
      <h1>
        <span id="span0">Lorem</span>
        <p id="p0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </h1>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h1>
        <span id="span1">Lorem2</span>
        <p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </h1>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h1>
        <span id="span2">Lorem3</span>
        <p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </h1> 
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! It worked like a charm. Both of your solutions work, but to be frank i dont really know what is the difference between them :)

Comment: OH... yea i get it, it isolates these specific paragraphs and spans so they dont collide with the rest of the content on the page. thank you very much once again

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#p0').hide();

$('span').on('click',function() {
    $('p').hide();
    $(this).next('p').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<li>
  <h1>
    <span id="span0" class="spanclick">Lorem</span>
    <p id="p0" class="par1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
  </h1>
</li>
<li>
  <h1>
    <span id="span1" class="spanclick">Lorem2</span>
    <p id="p1" class="par1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
  </h1>
</li>
<li>
  <h1>
    <span id="span2" class="spanclick">Lorem3</span>
    <p id="p2" class="par1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
  </h1> 
</li>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".par1").hide();
  $(".spanclick").click(function(){
    $(".par1").toggle();

  });
});
```