# if div is visible do nothing, else .show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code :

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <h1>
        <span id="span0">Lorem</span>
        <p id="p0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </h1>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h1>
        <span id="span1">Lorem2</span>
        <p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </h1>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h1>
        <span id="span2">Lorem3</span>
        <p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </h1> 
   </li>
...
</ul>
```

I have this JS function that shows a paragraph if its sibling span is clicked :

```
$('span[id^="span"]').click(function() {
    $('p[id^="p"]').hide( 900);
    $(this).next('p[id^="p"]').show(900);
});
```

The problem with it  is that it will trigger the animation even if the targeted paragraph is already shown(visible).

How would I write an " if " statement that would show targeted paragraph only if its current state is hidden, and do nothing if its already shown?

Comment: use toggle(900); $('p[id^="p"]').toggle(900); $(this).next('p[id^="p"]').toggle(900);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [on load and on click hide/show div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340389/on-load-and-on-click-hide-show-div)

Comment: @JohnSlegers i'm new to stack, so i dont know if it is a duplicate. i need a new function that stops an animation if a user clicks on a span repeatedly. should i have asked it in an edit on the question you are referring to?

Comment: @Nele : It seems to me that this question is just the next step in your thought process in solving the problem mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340389/on-load-and-on-click-hide-show-div. In such a case, editing your question and/or posting comments on the answers given is probably a better approach than asking a new question, because you're not supposed to ask more than one question to get an answer for the same problem. StackOverflow is pretty strict with respect to what's regarded as "duplicate" questions.

Comment: @JohnSlegers Thank you, ill keep that in mind

Comment: @JohnSlegers sorry if this is a stupid question, but what am i supposed to do now? I cant accept your edit because i got the answer to this question here, and not on my previous one... I don't want to deny the well deserved reputation to Nadeem Manzoor for the answer he gave.

Comment: @Nele : Don't worry about it. If others mods agree this is a duplicate question, this question will be closed. If not, it'll stay open. As long as you don't create question after question about the same problem, there should be no repercussions for you either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your click function to following

```
$('span[id^="span"]').click(function() {
    //check if already visible
    if(!$(this).next('p[id^="p"]').is(":visible")){
      $('p[id^="p"]').hide( 900);
      $(this).next('p[id^="p"]').show(900);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are missing a closing round bracket for the if statement , just before the curly bracket, but yea this is the solution i was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$(this).next('p[id^="p"]').show(900);
```

to

```
$(this).next('p[id^="p"]:hidden').show(900);
```

use [hidden](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector to select only those items which are hidden